# Storing each value into variables returned from JSON

Tags: json, flutter

I want to store each key-valye pair from JSON returned after sending a post request.

I have implemented code to hit the url:

```
Future<Initialdata> loadinitialdata(String url, {Map body} ) async{
    
    return http.post(url,
          body:body).then((http.Response response){
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }
    //JsonDecoder().convert(response.body);
     var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
    String initial_uid = extractdata["user"]["user_id"].toString();
    String initial_firstname = extractdata["user"]["first_name"];
    String initial_lastname = extractdata["user"]["last_name"];
    String initial_emailId = extractdata["user"]["email_id"];
    String initial_mobileNo = extractdata["user"]["mobile_no"];
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    return Initialdata.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    });
          
  }
```

This is the JSON returned:

```
"user": [
        {
            "user_id": 6568,
            "first_name": "mrunal",
            "last_name": "mrunal",
            "email_id": "kkkkk@gmail.com",
            "mobile_no": "6649734521",
            
            
        }
    ],
```

I get the following error:

```
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extractdata['user']` is a list, not an object. So you need to refer to zero index first, and then you get access to all the values. Just put `[0]` after `['user']`:

```
var extractdata = json.decode(response.body);
    String initial_uid = extractdata["user"][0]["user_id"].toString();
    String initial_firstname = extractdata["user"][0]["first_name"];
    String initial_lastname = extractdata["user"][0]["last_name"];
    String initial_emailId = extractdata["user"][0]["email_id"];
    String initial_mobileNo = extractdata["user"][0]["mobile_no"];
```